# shutil.move() throws TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found

Tags: python, shutil

I am trying to use shutil.move but getting error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "packageTest.py", line 202, in <module>
    writeResult()
  File "packageTest.py", line 92, in writeResult
    shutil.move(tempfile,'report.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 294, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

I am new to python and not sure what is wrong in this. Can anybody help me in this? I checked even whether i am trying to open the file twice but it is not so.

```
def writeResult():

    tempfile=NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    result='FAIL'
    with open('report.csv','rb') as infile,tempfile:
            csvreader=csv.DictReader(infile)
            fieldnames=csvreader.fieldnames
            csvwriter=csv.DictWriter(tempfile,fieldnames)
            csvwriter.writeheader()
            for node,row in enumerate(csvreader,1):
                    if(row['EXIST_IN_BOM']=='Yes'):
                            if(row['EXIST_IN_TAR']=='No'):
                                    csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,RESULT='FAIL'))
                                    csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,COMMENT='File is missing in package'))
                            else:
                                    result='PASS'

                    else:
                            if(row['EXIST_IN_TAR']=='Yes'):
                                    csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,RESULT='FAIL'))
                                    csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,COMMENT='File is missing in BOM'))


                    if(row['SIZE_IN_TAR']==row['SIZE_IN_ALPHA']):
                            result='PASS'
                    else:
                            csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,RESULT='FAIL'))
                            csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,COMMENT='File size not same'))
                    if(result=='PASS'):
                            csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,RESULT='PASS'))


    shutil.move(tempfile,'report.csv')
    return
```

**Edit:** The below code works though:

```
    tempfile=NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
with open('dict.csv','rb') as infile,tempfile:
        csvreader=csv.DictReader(infile)
        fieldnames=csvreader.fieldnames
        csvwriter=csv.DictWriter(tempfile,fieldnames)
        csvwriter.writeheader()
        for node,row in enumerate(csvreader,1):
                if(row['EmpId']=='119093'):
                        csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,Rank='1'))
                if(row['EmpId']=='119094'):
                        csvwriter.writerow(dict(row,Rank='2'))

shutil.move(tempfile.name,'dict.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

`shutil.move()` takes two filenames, not a file-like and a filename. If you want to copy the contents of a file-like to a filename then open the filename in write mode and use `shutil.copyfileobj()` instead.

Comment: please see the Edit part. shutil.move also works if we would like to... the same type of file i have there also. But i am not sure why it is not working this time

Comment: Read the first sentence I wrote.

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake that i didn't see so minor thing...i just changed the code as shutil.move(tempfile.name, "report.csv"). Thank you so much for pointing that out... I guess too much of work is making me blackout